# the method '[]' cant be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. when i try fetch data from api

Tags: flutter, api

try to use data from api with http package but i get null safty problem
the method '[]' cant be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null

```
return ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapShot.data[index]['thumbnailUrl']),),
                title: Text(snapShot.data[index]['title']),
                subtitle: Text("${snapShot.data[index]['id']}"),
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell dart that the variable is not null (only for the first time), this can be done by the use of `!` after the variable, for instance if the error tells that `snapShot.data` maybe null, type `snapShot.data!` another example could be `snapShot.data[index]['id']!`

Comment: i tried to do that but get same error

Comment: @MohammedAli For which line or variable is this error produced?

Comment: image ,title and the id the error in first bracket of index

Comment: Did you try `snapShot.data[index]['thumbnailUrl']!`, `snapShot.data[index]['title']!` ,`snapShot.data[index]['id']!` ?

Comment: yes still get same error